# User input fields better with DIVs or forms for a webpage that just calculates a formula?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to have 6 input fields in a webpage. If the user presses a button the 6 fields expand to 7,8, 9, or 10 fields. The fields are editable and come with a preset value. With the input from the user (or the preset values) a final value is calculated via a formula.

1. Is it better to use a `form` for the fields or `DIV`s?
2. Should I use `JavaScript` or something else I am not thinking about yet?
3. Should I use `AJAX` when getting the values or is it not needed in this case?
4. I thought about using an excel like editor made with `jQuery` https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples but it seems overkill for my needs plus I would need to edit a lot of it since I want a simple display of the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a form as you're asking the users for their data to be input. This will also trigger the keyboard on mobile/tablet devices if you're also targeting those platforms.

Javascript is fine for this, unless you want to hide the formula you're using (as they will be able to see it if they view your source).

Do you need to use AJAX? Are the pre-populated values going to change that much? If not, then no, it's just adding extra work when you could just have an array of values.

Comment: Ah this seems to be the answer I was looking for. Thank you, I will mark it answered I just want to see if I get some more opinions. It's fine if the formula is displayed; but I might delete the spaces and use a separate js file to make it slightly more difficult for it to be seen. 


I hadn't thought about divs having issues on mobile so this is important. I might want to use AJAX since I am doing something finance related so at least part of the values will change a lot. I will think about this more; how complex I want to make it.